# Calibration extrinsic Camera_lidar

Tags: calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to to calibrate camera with a lidar ,after some search i think the best way is use the toolbox radlocc (MATLAB)
for this toolbox is necessary  to acquired data from the camera and the lidar in the same time by create a service with node subscriber to camera and node subscribrer to hokuyo the probelem i don't know how i can create this service for save a script data time (Lidar) for each capture of camera .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208468/calibration-extrinsic-camera_lidar/) by [khairidine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22337/khairidine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-07-12**:
How did you store the timestamps for the camera for the RADLOCC toolbox? I could collect the laser and camera data as a rosbag and convert the laser scan into ASCII format.
I did not understand the list where I should provide timestamps of the images. Any help on that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going to assume that the camera and lidar unit are static, relative to each other, i.e. they don't have relative motion between frames.

In this case, the calibration only needs to be completed once. You can do this offline with a collection of scans.
Once you have completed calibration to achieve the transformation matrix, all you need to do is use the matrix to translate the camera coordinate system to that of the lidar (or vice versa). eg P_cam = Mtx*P_lidar

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0